# How can I handle the results of two level nested promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

I will get 'undefined' as the promise result if the branch *caseA* is running.

What a better way to handle this case?

```
    function getNumsPromiseCall(){
        nums = [1,2,3]
        if (caseA) {
            var nestedPromiseResult = Promise.all(mainTasks).then(function(response){
                var secondLevelPromises = prepare(response);
                Promise.all(secondLevelPromises).then(function(subResponses)){
                    subResponses.forEach(function(r){
                        nums.push(r);
                    })
                    return nums;
                }
            })
            return Promise.resolve(nestedPromiseResult);
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(nums);
        }    
    }

    getNumsPromiseCall.then(function(nums){
        // I will be only getting undefined for nums for the case A branch.    
    })
```

Comment: `.then(function(subResponses)){`... Syntax error.

Comment: nothing is returned in `.then(function(response){`, therefore `nestedPromiseResult` WILL be `undefined`

Comment: Does `prepare()` really return an array of promises, or is it an array of values? If it's the latter, then you can leave out the inner `Promise.all(...).then()` and work directly with `subResponses`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - This is clearly pseudo-code so I think this is just conceptual for the purposes of creating a scenario with nested promises.  Certainly each mainTask could process it's own response rather than adding a whole separate `Promise.all()` step for that (which is perhaps where you were going).  But, I don't think this question is really about that kind of stuff because it's not real code that we can participate at that level of detail.

Comment: @jfriend00, agreed, and your answer addresses the question well. I'm just seeking to give the OP maximum benefit from his question. I'm pretty certain there's more to be learned here than simply including `return `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the inner, nested promises and make sure that `nums` is the return value from the most deeply nested promise:

```
function getNumsPromiseCall() {
    let nums = [1,2,3];
    if (caseA) {
        return Promise.all(mainTasks).then(function(response){
            let secondLevelPromises = prepare(response);
            return Promise.all(secondLevelPromises).then(function(subResponses) {
                subResponses.forEach(function(r){
                    nums.push(r);
                });
                return nums;
            });
        });
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve(nums);
    }    
}

getNumsPromiseCall.then(function(nums){
    // You  will see nums here    
});
```

Whenever you have a new promise inside a `.then()` handler, you need to return that promise in order to link it into the parent chain.  This makes sure that the parent promise waits for the inner promise and it allows the inner code to control the eventual resolved value of the chain (via returning the promise and returning a value from the inner `.then()`).

An inner promise that is not returned from a `.then()` handler becomes a completely separate promise chain (I refer to it as fire and forget) that the parent doesn't wait for and that does not influence the resolved value of the parent and whose errors are silent (nearly always a coding mistake).

There are rarely legitimate reasons for not returning an inner promise when you explicitly don't want the parent to wait for it and when you don't want to communicate back a value or error from the separate promise chain.  The only example I've seen for this in my code is some sort of cleanup operation (like closing a file) that you wouldn't have anything useful to do if it caused an error anyway and don't need the parent to wait for it to complete.

---

FYI, this is a bit of code that would benefit (in readability) from using `async/await`:

```
async function getNumsPromiseCall() {
    let nums = [1,2,3];
    if (caseA) {
        let responses = await Promise.all(mainTasks);
        let secondLevelPromises = prepare(responses);
        let subResponses = await Promise.all(secondLevelPromises);
        subResponses.forEach(function(r) {
            nums.push(r);
        });
    }    
    return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNumsPromiseCall(){
    nums = [1,2,3]
    if (caseA) {
        var nestedPromiseResult = Promise.all(mainTasks).then(function(response){
            var secondLevelPromises = prepare(response);
            return Promise.all(secondLevelPromises).then(function(subResponses)){ //you missed return here.
                subResponses.forEach(function(r){
                    nums.push(r);
                })
                return nums;
            }
        })
        return Promise.resolve(nestedPromiseResult);
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve(nums);
    }    
}

getNumsPromiseCall().then(function(nums){
    // I will be only getting undefined for nums for the case A branch.    
})
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to your code would make your answer better.